# DinkToPdf - HTML div on one pdf page

Tags: html, css, .net, pdf, dinktopdf

I generate PDF from HTML with DinkToPdf, but I have a problem with some `div`, because half of it is in one page and second half is on another page. Sometimes only one word is on the next page.

Is there any solution how to set that whole `div` will be on the same page? The best would be through html/css. For example if there is enough space for whole `div`, it will be on the same page where the text continue. If there is not enough space, the whole `div` will be on the new page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. The css for the `div` should have this:

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```